# How to call wcf service using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, rest, wcf, webforms

I'm trying to call a WCF service from ajax call. This is my ajax call:

```
     $j.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                context: this,
                async: false,
                url: appServicePath + "Student/GetRolesByUserId",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "userId": userId }),
                success: this.getRolesByIdResponse,
                error: this.getRolesByIdFailure
            }
        );
```

when I test my service using Fiddler I'm able to get the roles of the user that I'm passing its value from ajax but when I call the service from my application I get an error: 405 Method Not Allowed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think this problem is due to cross-domain, the problem generates an OPTIONS request, So the method is not allowed. If you put the script in the same domain as the webservice, you won't have this problem.

[image: IIS physical path]

Here is Http 405 method document.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5

You now need to turn on cross-domain support for a WCF application hosted on the web server side.

**Web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

</system.webServer>

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin")&&Request.HttpMethod=="OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Feel free to contact me if you have any questions.